# I am trying to filter data from a dataset and place it into a grouped boxplot but it is giving me errors in the image

Tags: python, csv, boxplot

I am trying to use data from a dataset and visualize the stats into a grouped visual of a histogram and boxplot. I have tried different methods but each time it gives me a different error and ultimately doesn't seem to work.

This is the prompt for what I am trying to do: Create a stacked plot (histogram with a boxplot) using the Seaborn package. Import the correct libraries you will need seaborn, pandas and pyplot (from matplotlib). You should create a boxplot that has cylinders as the x-axis and acceleration as the y-axis. Adjust sizes so that it looks clean and readable. Build a histogram for Acceleration that is divided by different numbers of Cylinders, but only inlcude cars with 4 and 8 cylinders.

I was able to work out all of the prompts, except for formatting my boxplot correctly. Here's my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/mpg-Theo_Tuggle.csv')    

text = 'Theo'
ax.text(0.7, 0.6, text, fontsize=10, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure);

f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})
sns.set(style="ticks")
flierprops = dict(marker='o', markersize=4, markerfacecolor='none', linestyle='none', markeredgecolor='gray')

df_filtered = df2[df2['Cylinders'] == 8 | df2['Cylinders'] == 4]
sns.histplot(data=df2[df2['Cylinders']==8], x="Acceleration", ax=ax_hist, kde=True)
sns.histplot(data=df2[df2['Cylinders']==4], x="Acceleration", ax=ax_hist, kde=True, color="orange")
ax = sns.boxplot(y=df_filtered.Cylinders, x=df_filtered.Acceleration, ax=ax_box,  orient='h', fliersize=20, width=15, linewidth=1, flierprops=flierprops)  

ax_box.set(yticks=[])
ax_box.set(xticks=[])
ax_box.set_xlabel('')
sns.despine(ax=ax_hist)                        
sns.despine(ax=ax_box, left=True, bottom=True)
```

The error happens the line beginning with "ax = sns.boxplot...". The error says:

```
<ipython-input-21-b52ee904d028> in <cell line: 15>()
     13 flierprops = dict(marker='o', markersize=4, markerfacecolor='none', linestyle='none', markeredgecolor='gray')
     14 
---> 15 df_filtered = df2[df2['Cylinders'] == 8 | df2['Cylinders'] == 4]
     16 sns.histplot(data=df2[df2['Cylinders']==8], x="Acceleration", ax=ax_hist, kde=True)
     17 sns.histplot(data=df2[df2['Cylinders']==4], x="Acceleration", ax=ax_hist, kde=True, color="orange")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1525     @final
   1526     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527         raise ValueError(
   1528             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
```

I have tried assigning a new variable to that filtered data, using two separate statements, using the 'or' operator, and a few other syntax things. I just need to have a boxplot showing 4 and 8 cylinders.

Comment: Please give the full traceback, not just the error

Comment: `df_filtered = df2[df2['Cylinders'] == 8 | df2['Cylinders'] == 4]` should be `df_filtered = df2[(df2['Cylinders'] == 8) | (df2['Cylinders'] == 4)]` so that each condition is evaluated individually